# ¿Cómo desarrollar en R un código que me permita encontrar un número decimal a binario, el cual debe contener números y letras minúsculas?

Tags: r, rstudio

Lo intento, pero no lo tengo claro aún.
No sé cómo poner las letras minúsculas dentro la función.

```
binario<-function(decimal) {
  bsum<-0
  bexp<-1
  while (decimal > 0) {
    div<-decimal %% 2
    decimal<-floor(decimal / 2)
    bsum<-bsum + div * bexp
    bexp<-bexp * 10
  }
  return(bsum)
}
decimal<-readline("Insertar numero decimal: ")
decimal<-as.numeric(decimal)
bsum<-binario(decimal)
cat("En binario: ", bsum)
```

Comment: Tendrías que explicarte mejor qué es lo que pretendes. Encontrar un número decimal a binario ¿qué quieres decir? Y luego no entiendo, si son números ¿qué es eso de contener números y letras y en minúsculas?

Comment: Adiero al pedido de aclaraciones, lo que tienes ahora es un función que transforma un número en otro en base 2, y parece que lo hace bien. ¿Tal vez estás buscando una conversión a hexadecimal?

Comment: Sí, por favor. Podrías explicar mejor.